# Program can't find libboost_program_options.so.1.47.0 at runtime

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

Since I don't have root permission to install Boost C++ library, I installed it under my home local. When compiling, I used:
`g++  -I/home/name/local/boost_1_47_0 -L/home/name/local/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib foo.cc -o foo -lboost_program_options`

but at runtime, it goes:
`error while loading shared libraries: libboost_program_options.so.1.47.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

and ldd gives:
`libboost_program_options.so.1.47.0 => not found`

I also tried to specify the absolute path of the library, but it doesn't work either:
`g++ /home/name/local/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.47.0 -I/home/name/local/boost_1_47_0 -L/home/name/local/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib foo.cc -o foo`

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to instruct the run-time linker where to find the library:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/name/local/boost_1_47_0/stage/lib
```

Then rerun your application.

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't a good long term solution to the problem. Eventually you'll either want to require that boost_program_options find its way into the system library search path sans LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or use a runpath with a local shared library. See http://blogs.oracle.com/rie/date/20040710

Comment: If you cannot install to the system places I would use static libraries for the release so LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not required

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie, so don't take my words too seriously. Furthermore, this question is several months old and I guess solved long ago. Nevertheless, here's what I think.

You specify the library path to the linker, so the program compiles and links fine. However, when you try to execute the binary, it looks for the libs in the environment defined path.

I guess this can be fixed by typing into bash

export PATH=$PATH:path_to_your_library_folder

Best Regards
Miroslav